# Optimizing simple query that takes 1 minute to execute

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I have this rather simple SQL query, but it takes almost a minute to execute:

```
SELECT
 i.id,
 ...,
 a.id AS albums_id,
 ...,
 u.id AS users_id,
 ...
FROM
 images i
  LEFT JOIN albums a ON i.albums_id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN users u ON a.users_id = u.id
WHERE
 a.access = 'public'
 AND i.num_of_views > 0
ORDER BY
 i.num_of_views DESC
LIMIT
 0, 60
```

Result of EXPLAIN for the above query:

[image: http://i.min.us/ibeAnM.png]

Tables involved:

`images` (~4,822,000 rows), `albums` (~149,000 rows), `users` (~43,000 rows)

Relevant indexes:

`albums`: access(access,num_of_images,album_time), access_2(access,num_of_images,num_of_all_comments,album_time), users_id(users_id,album_time)

`images`: browser_2(num_of_views), albums_id(albums_id,image_order)

All tabels are InnoDB, running on MySql v5.1.47

So how do I bring this down to under a second?

Please leave a comment if you need any additional info.

edit: `users` table can be joined either with `albums` or `images` does not matter to me.

edit2: moving `a.access = 'public'` from `WHERE` to `JOIN` does indeed solve my problem, but the results returned are not correct (I get images from albums that are not public), putting the `a.access ...` in both `WHERE` and `JOIN` slows the query down even more than before.

Comment: Are you sure you're even getting the correct results? The fact that you are referencing `a.access` in your where clause negates the left join on albums and effectively turns it into an inner join. If a left join is truly needed, then `a.access = 'public'` should be part of the join condition instead.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli I'm joining by albums's PRIMARY KEY (a.id = i.albums_id), how could I put `a.access = 'public'` into that? The results are correct btw.

Comment: Please do not use tabs within the code formatted text

Comment: @OMG Ponies fixed, may I ask why?

Comment: Your join condition would become `...LEFT JOIN albums a ON i.albums_id = a.id AND a.access = 'public'...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a little confusion going on here w/r/t the impact that a filter can have on a LEFT JOIN vs an INNER JOIN.

Jan, if what you are trying to ask in your query is "Get all images for all albums that are public, and get the users of those albums as well" then you do not want a left join, you want an inner join. A left join will return all images for all albums, but it will also return all images that have no matching album. You can add "and a.id IS NOT NULL" but that's the same as an INNER JOIN.

I believe what you want is the following:

```
SELECT
 i.id,
 ...,
 a.id AS albums_id,
 ...,
 u.id AS users_id,
 ...
FROM images i
  INNER JOIN albums a ON i.albums_id = a.id AND a.access = 'public'
  INNER JOIN users u ON a.users_id = u.id
WHERE i.num_of_views > 0
ORDER BY i.num_of_views DESC
LIMIT 0, 60
```

If you left join albums to users you could return all albums that don't have users. Not sure which one you want.

Comment: The performance was still bad. But when I forced MySQL to use the PRIMARY index everything started working as it should.

Comment: What's the EXPLAIN w/o the force index on the query?

Answer (score 3):

Add an index on `albums.users_id`. I also agree with the comments regarding `a.access = 'public'`. But the index should help either way.

#### UPDATE

Since the key above exists. Try adjusting the order of your `JOIN`, i.e. move `users` above albums or make a different table the primary. In rare cases this can help. Also to better join `albums` try:

```
LEFT JOIN albums a ON (i.albums_id = a.id AND a.access = 'public')
```

#### UPDATE

Based on the comments, I would remove as many of the `LEFT JOIN` as possible. As I am not sure what you require in your results, I will only show it for `albums`. This will not only decrease the result set, but solve the problem for applying the filter.

```
JOIN albums a ON (i.albums_id = a.id AND a.access = 'public')
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have that index, please see my update

Comment: There's no need for the brackets in the ON criteria.

Comment: @OMG, understood. Just a personal habit.

Comment: Chhers! This brings the query down to 0.0016 sec :) I'm a moron I know :)

Comment: Darn, should have made my comment an answer! :-)

Comment: @Joe, I gave you a shout out ;) @Jan, did you just add the a.access?

Comment: Well crap, I found out that I still have to have `a.access = 'public'` in the `WHERE` part (otherwise I was getting wrong results back) and that brings the query back to where it was time wise. But the same thing wroks in some other cases. So I need help again :\

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make any sense. You shouldn't need it in the `WHERE` clause if it is already part of the `JOIN`. You sure you were getting the *right* results before.

Comment: It makes sense b/c he's choosing a LEFT JOIN, so placing a filter from a right-sided table into the ON clause will not cause it to act as a filter.

Comment: @David, point taken. Forgot about the `LEFT JOIN`. The question becomes then is the `LEFT JOIN` necessary... I feel like this query has inherit problems beyond performance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your most recent comments, you should use an INNER JOIN to albums instead of a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT
 i.id,
 ...,
 a.id AS albums_id,
 ...,
 u.id AS users_id,
 ...
FROM images i
  INNER JOIN albums a ON i.albums_id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN users u ON a.users_id = u.id
WHERE a.access = 'public'
 AND i.num_of_views > 0
ORDER BY i.num_of_views DESC
LIMIT 0, 60
```

Comment: That's slow too. If I put the `a.access='public` in both the JOIN and WHERE and force it to use the PRIMARY index, then it works. A almost identical query (instead of num_of_views, there's num_of_all_comments, that is indexd the same way as num_of_views) works without the forcing perfectly. I should also mention that this slow down happened just recently. A couple of 100k records ago everything was working OK.

Comment: Have you tried running an [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html) on your tables?